# jQuery AJAX POST Send Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
  var result = confirm("You want to Subscribe to our Newsletter?");
  var emailAddress = $("#subscribeEmail").val();

  if (result == true) {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/php/subscribeNewsletter.php',
      data: '{"email": "' + emailAddress + '"}',
      complete: function(r){
    alert(r.responseText);
    }

    });


  }
```

I believe the problem is to do with:
 data: '{"email": "' + emailAddress + '"}',

I am receiving an empty $_POST array on the server side of things.

Comment: try with this  data: JSON.stringify({email: emailAddress}),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an object literal, not a string:

```
data: {email: emailAddress },
```

jQuery will transform the object into the URL encoded key/value pairs, which will be picked up in the `$_POST` array on the PHP side.

Your current code is actually sending a JSON string as the raw POST data. jQuery is seeing the data type is a string, and so it doesn't do any processing, so you'd have to access the raw POST data on the PHP side and do a JSON decode to get it.

Answer (score 1):

yes problem is: `data: '{"email": "' + emailAddress + '"}'`, it should be object:

```
...
data: {"email": emailAddress},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

provide the `data` attribute in the ajax call as a json object instead of string.

like

```
data: {"email": emailAddress },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
$.get('/Presentation/AjaxData/History.aspx', { itemID: itemid }, function (data) {
        $('.history-listing-tabs>.tab-item').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format

```
data: {email: emailAddress}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better pass data to a variable and use it while sending,

```
 var temp = 'email:' + emailAddress;
 ...
 data: temp;
 .....
```